# Добавить элементу высоту с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Есть блок div с картинкой заданной в процентах, т.е. взависимости от разрешения экрана ширина и высота блока меняется.

Как передать эту высоту + условно 100px другому элементу через JS?

**Например:**

```
<!-- Блок с изображением -->
<div class="kartinka">
   <img src="img.jpg" alt="Какая-то картинка" />
</div>
```

Стили изображения:

```
   .kartinka img{
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       max-width: 400px;
      }
```

И также имеется div который никакак не относится к изображению, но ему надо передать значения текущей высоты + 100px

```
<div class="other-wrapper">
   <p>Всякое содержимое</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее метод offsetHeight должен получать высоту элемента вне зависимости от того, в каких единицах она указана и указана ли вообще (как в вашем случае, вы ведь не знаете, какой высоты картинка будет).

```
var height = document.querySelector(".kartinka").offsetHeight;
var heightPlus100 = height + 100;
```

В `heightPlus100` запихивается конечный требуемый результат. Если вам его надо присвоить как высоту другому блоку, то сделайте так:

```
document.querySelector(".other-wrapper").style.height = heightPlus100 + "px";
```